# How to add title page in twocolumn springer journal format in latex

Tags: titles

I am using `[twocolumn]{svhour3}` class file in springer journal format. in that I want a separate title page containing title, author(s) name, address and foot note. for that this is my code.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%

    \smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{blindtext} % For dummy text
%\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{caption}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{titlepage}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
%\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
%\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
  \pagestyle{plain}
 \usepackage{latexsym}
%>>>> uncomment following to start page numbering at 301 
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\makeatletter
%\use
%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%


\title{this is my title}
\author{author 1 \and author 2}
\institute{Department of Computer Science \& Engineering \at
              institute name\\
              \email{abc@gmail.com}
           \and
           Department of Computer Science \& Engineering \at
              institute name\\
              \email{abc@gmail.com}
}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor





\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\begin{titlingpage}
```

Comment: Springer will simply revert your change.

Comment: Please decide on *either* using the `titlepage` environment directly, *or* by using the global option `titlepage`. Using it directly *with* `maketitle` leads to rubbish.

Comment: Are you submitting to a Springer journal? They have no mechanisms for titlepages. It might be better to start with `article` or `scrartcl` or `memoir` (in article mode).

Comment: Yes! I am submitting to springer journal and they are asking for title page (containing title, author's name and address).

Comment: They are providing classes and templates, if they want a titlepage from you, they should provide the tools. The class you are mentioning needs to be hacked to get a titlepage, still, we don't know how it is supposed to look like. Can you ask the Springer guys for references?

Comment: Is there any result to report?